# If $xy = yx$ and $\lvert x\rvert$ and $\lvert y\rvert$ are coprime, then $\lvert xy\rvert = lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to prove the following: If $G$ is a finite group (not necessarily Abelian) and if $xy = yx$ and $\lvert x\rvert$ and $\lvert y\rvert$ are coprime, then $\lvert xy\rvert = lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)$.

I have a part of this because
$$
(xy)^{lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)} = x^{lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)}y^{lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)} = e
$$
so $\lvert xy\rvert$ divides $lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)$.

But I can't quite figure out the other direction. I had thought about saying something like if $(xy)^i = x^iy^i = e$, then somehow get to what I want but I am not sure.

Comment: Note that, if $|x|$ and $|y|$ are coprime, then their $lcm$ equals their product.

Comment: @Crostul: Ah, now I see it. Thanks. Feel free to write an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x^ay^b=e$. 
Then $y^{-b\cdot |x|} =e$ so $b\cdot |x|$ is a multiple of $|y|$, hence - by being coprimes - so is $b$. 
Similarly we get that $a$ must be a multiple of $|x|$.